# Numeric to Alphabetic Organization

Tags: code-golf, sorting, file-system

I have a list of images grouped numerically (`YI0.png`, `YI1.png`...`YI20479.png`). I want them sorted alphabetically, like so:

```
YI0.png -> YIA.png
YI1.png -> YIAA.png
```

without my last image having 20479 `A`s in it.

### Input

A directory name.

### Output

All files in that directory will be alphabetically renamed.

### Constraints

- The pattern is always `Prefix` `Number`.`Extension`
- There are no subdirectories
- All files in the directory adhere to the pattern
- `Number` starts at 0
- `Prefix` doesn't contain numbers

### Example

Directory consisting of `Pie0.txt`, `Pie1.txt`, all the way to `Pie11.txt` would be renamed to `PieA.txt`, `PieB.txt`, all the way to `PieL.txt`.

If it goes to `Pie28.txt`, they would be renamed like so:

```
Pie0.txt -> PieA.txt
Pie1.txt -> PieAA.txt
Pie2.txt -> PieAB.txt
Pie3.txt -> PieB.txt
Pie28.txt -> PieZ.txt
```

Remember, this is **[code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf)**, so the answer in the shortest bytes wins.

Comment: will all files in the dir be of the form `"some_letters_that_are_always_the_sameNumber.txt"`?

Comment: Yes, it will have a pattern of `PrefixNumber.Extension` @Maltysen

Comment: will be ever have three length codes?

Comment: Will the directory only have plain files or can it e.g. have subdirectories which need to be ignored or recursed into ?

Comment: Anyways, I'm not sure I like a challenge that needs to do system commands and especially filename parsing (e.g. is ``\\`` or ``/`` the separator, can files start with `.` etc.) . An input that is a list of simple filenames with an output that are the corresponding translated names seems nicer to me

Comment: Can there be holes in the sequence of numbers ? Can numbers have extra leading zeros ? Can the prefix contain digits ? Does the sequence always start with `0` ?

Comment: Yes, there will be varied length codes (remember, I have 20479 files). The prefix and extension will only contain alphabetical characters. There are no subdirectories or different patterned files.

Comment: Will the numeric suffix have leading zeroes? If you sort the numbers between 1 and 100 alphabetically you get [1, 10, 100, 11, 12 ..], but if they have leading zeroes you get [001, 002, 003 ..]

Comment: @BlackCap they do not

Comment: Since there are different OS in the world, can we not write a program or function which takes a list of strings in the format you defined and outputs a list of new names in the same order as the input list such that the output list is in alphabetic order? Also can we use digits and lowercase letters in our new names (since standard alphabetic sorting would be 0<9<A<Z<a<z)?

Comment: @Jonathan Allan only letters, not numbers. Lowercase and uppercase are allowed though.

Comment: This needs a spec. At present we have to guess what it might be from two examples.

Comment: Imagine a hyperdictionary but culled to only have the amount of "words" as the numbers. Once I run the perl example I will have more examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Perl, 65 bytes

Assumes the number sequence starts with 0 and has no holes (or duplicates if there are extra leading zeros). No error checking.
Assumes only plain files, filenames do not start with `.` and the user can enter the directory.

Run with the directory as argument

```
alphaorg.pl directory
```

`alphaorg.pl`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
chdir pop;$a=A;@F=sort map$a++,<*>;rename$_,s/\d+/$F[$&]/r for<*>
```

If the directory name can't contain digits and your sytem will accept `/` as directory separator (unix and windows do), this 61 byte version is shorter (give directory name on STDIN here):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -ln
$a=A;@F=sort map$a++,@;=<$_/*>;rename$_,s/\d+/$F[$&]/r for@
```

Answer (score 1):

## Haskell - 97 bytes

I probably picked the wrong language; Haskell has painfully long names for IO operations

```
r p=do f<-getDirectoryContents p;sequence_.zipWith renameFile(sort f).sort$permutations['A'..'Z']
```

*(this program has O(26^26) in run-time unless you're on a quantum computer)*

Comment: Maybe I am on a Quantum Computer :^) no lol I wish though

Comment: @moo_we_all_do You could be- IBM is handing out access to a 6 qubit quantum computer at the moment (I got it, so it can't be that hard). 

Unfortunately you're gonna need about 123 qubits to run this program in real time ..

Comment: I also now have access to it. If I had $100 dollars, I would pay you $100 to write this program in QASM. That would astound me!

Comment: @moo_we_all_do `R x|-Zip(Sort x).Sort$Permutations['A'..'Z']`. This is QML, a haskell inspired quantum language with a compiler written in haskell: sneezy.cs.nott.ac.uk/qml Obviusly you can't read files or anything yet, so you have to pass it the file names as a list of strings. It is in my opinion by far the best effort at a high level quantum language as of now. Don't ask me why he chose to have uppercase names for functions